# Is it necessary/recommended to include both file and class documentation for PHP classes?

Tags: php, documentation, conventions, phpdoc

I am trying to maintain the best coding practices and have been following PEAR coding standards for PHP while writing my web application. I am using [phpcs](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) to help guide me while writing my code, however, it is nagging me to include a file doc as well as a class doc for my PHP classes.

The rule can found [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standards.inline-documentation):

> All class files must contain a "file-level" docblock at the top of each file and a "class-level" docblock immediately above each class. Examples of such docblocks can be found below.

**File documentation**

```
/**
* Short description for file
*
* Long description for file (if any)...
*
* LICENSE: Some license information
*
* @category   Zend
* @package    Zend_Magic
* @subpackage Wand
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
* @license    http://framework.zend.com/license   BSD License
* @version    $Id:$
* @link       http://framework.zend.com/package/PackageName
* @since      File available since Release 1.5.0
*/
```

**Class documentation**

```
/**
* Short description for class
*
* Long description for class (if any)...
*
* @category   Zend
* @package    Zend_Magic
* @subpackage Wand
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
* @license    http://framework.zend.com/license   BSD License
* @version    Release: @package_version@
* @link       http://framework.zend.com/package/PackageName
* @since      Class available since Release 1.5.0
* @deprecated Class deprecated in Release 2.0.0
*/
```

The two docs are so close in format and annotations that it has me wondering if its even necessary have both in the same class file? Especially when implementing one class per PHP file the description at the doc level and the class level will be identical. What are the well established and respected standards and universal practice within the PHP community dictating now with respect to this kind of documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coding standards have moved towards requiring that a file with a class definition in it should contain only one class and nothing else.  So, *if* this one-class-per-file requirement exists, then it does seem to make the file-docblock-and-class-docblock feel redundant.  However, since nothing beyond that CS requirement does prevent having other things in the file, then the file does still need a way to document itself.

Generated docs generally have docs for the files themselves, not just the classes.  The file docblock is your way to control what you want displayed on those doc pages.  If you just want to dupe what's also in the class docblock, it's your choice, but not required.

If this file only had constant being defined in it, which itself required its own docblock, we might be having this conversation about them :-)

Comment: Just saw this now. Good enough explanation for me. Thank you!